# How is this question too broad

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Open a suitcase with a numeric lock when you forgot the key code](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/343/open-a-numeric-lock-when-you-forgot-the-key-code) this question of mine has been closed now for the second time, this is not a rant, so please read the question as objectively as possible.

The reason I decided to post here was because I feel that this has been put on hold for two invalid reasons.  First it was felt this is off topic, and then reopened.  It was also felt that it was too broad, so I narrowed it to just focus on suitcases, but this is now been closed as too broad even now, I just feel that the real reason is something else.

Specifically I want to ensure that the community here is aware of the implications of such questions being deleted.  If how to open a locked suitcase is too broad, that too with a specific type of lock (numeric) then I guess there is something wrong with the definition.

To make my point I would like to equate this SE to a computer hacking SE, would how to break a specific weak password (lets say Dictionary words) be too broad there?  Again I am not specifically worried about my question being closed or deleted or whatever, but we cannot assume that this is dangerous and close the question for one reason or the other.

There are other questions too, like [How can I test for electrical current through bare wires without a meter?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-can-i-test-for-electrical-current-in-bare-wires-without-a-meter#comment2058_403) where people just become afraid of something and vote for a close, this itself I think is a very dangerous trend that needs to be avoided if this site were to live.  Some lifehacks will be dangerous and we have to accept it, take precautions rather than closing our eyes to it.

Comment: Could you create another meta for the "dangerous / criminal" discussion? I think thats a whole different discussion and an important one.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs this partially addresses it http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/can-we-stop-this-close-war

Answer (score 4):

I think this question is too broad.

There are many (!) different locks, many of which have different options on how you could open them without destroying them. Without knowing the specific branch of lock in use there is no chance to answer this without guessing.

So this question is not answerable within a few paragraphs, answers that aim at completeness need to be overly long. Thats the very definition of too broad.